# Wordpress query and order by date

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to create a list of 10 products with a publication date in the future ordered most recent to most in the future. The publication date is stored as longtext in an Advanced Custom Field called "publication_daet" in Ymd format. The code I'm using is below but the results are not as expected (results are below the code block). Any ideas?

```
<section id="recent">
<ul class="row-fluid">
    <?php

    $today = date('m/d/Y');

        $args = array(
     'post_type'        => 'product',
     'showposts' => 10,
     'meta_key'     => 'publication_date',
     'meta_value'   => $today,
     'meta_compare' => '>',
     'order' => 'ASC',
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>

                <li class="span3">    

                    <a id="id-<?php the_id(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">

                      <b><?php $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', get_field('publication_date'));?><?php echo $date->format('m/d/Y'); ?></b>: <?php the_title(); ?>

                    </a>
                </li><!-- /span3 -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

</ul><!-- /row-fluid -->
</section><!-- /recent -->
```

Results:

11/20/2013: The Capitals

09/03/2015: Orphan Black Card Game

07/10/2014: Sons of Anarchy Men of Mayhem

07/25/2013: Unicorno Frenzies

06/25/2015: Medieval Academy

07/03/2014: Krosmaster Arena DuelPack

01/29/2015: Redacted

06/15/2010: 3:16 Carnage Amongst the Stars

04/29/2015: BattleTech Recon Lance Pack

12/17/2014: Duke Siege Engines Middle Ages

Answer (score 0):

Your date format in your custom field is correct. Your date format needs to be unix time stamp or in the format of `Y-m-d`.

However, the format of today's date is incorrect. Unlike the `date_query` field, custom fields compare literally, no convertions are done to any value, so your formats of values to be compared **must** match. In short, if your date is stored in a custom field as unix timestamp, your date to be compared must be unix timestamp, otherwise your comparisons fail. The same with date formats, if your date is saved as `Ymd`, your format to compare must be `Ymd`. If your format is `Y-m-d`, your format to compare must be `Y-m-d`. If these format don't match, your comparison is doomed

To solve your issue, change the value of `$today` to match the same format as your custom field